# Not able to post the select option value in express js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, pug

I wanted to make a signup page.In my user model schema , I have a security question and answer field for the users to input.The security questions are in the select html tag for the users to choose.My user schema model looks like this-

```
   var mongoose = require('mongoose');
   // declare schema object.
   var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

   var userSchema = new Schema({

          userName          : {type:String,default:'',required:true},
          firstName             : {type:String,default:''},
          lastName              : {type:String,default:''},
          email             : {type:String,default:''},
          mobileNumber          : {type:Number,default:''},
          password          : {type:String},
          securityQusetion  : {type:String},
          securityAnswer        : {type:String}



          });


          mongoose.model('User',userSchema);
```

I'm using jade templating engine.On the mongodb database I get all the other data except security question.My jade view file and the signup route is here 
 [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rahuljhawar88/p8ns89uc/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could only be a minor thing but I noticed that in the following line:

```
securityQusetion  : {type:String}
```

"Security Question" was spelled incorrectly. Perhaps the typo is causing errors in Jade file.

Comment: no problems! could you please mark my answer as the accepted answer for other users. Thanks